# MySQL fetch is empty (but acutally isn't)

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem with fetching data from a MySQL database. It fetches rows, and when printing the result with print_r it looks correct, but when getting one item in the array is always empty, and I don't have a clue why!

If I use phpMyAdmin I can see all rows in the database and they look correct.

Anyone got an idea?

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());;
    mysqli_select_db($con, $database) or die("Cannot select DB");

    $r = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Question FROM TempQuestions") or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    Print "Rows ". mysqli_num_rows($r) . "<br>"; // Returns 10 rows

    while ($dbResult = mysqli_fetch_array( $r)) {
        print_r($dbResult); // Prints the question like Array ([0] => The question in DB, [Question] => The question in DB)
        Print "<br><br>";
        Print "Question: ";
        Print $dbresult['Question']; // Is always empty!
        Print $dbresult[0]; // Is always empty!
        Print "<br><br>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($r);
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You're changing the variable name from `$dbResult` to `$dbresult` - PHP variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: (Also - you're calling `mysql_error()` if the query fails, but you're using mysqli_; that should be `mysqli_error($con)`)

Comment: use under score to delimit word in variables.

Comment: @JungsuHeo lowerCamelCase is allowed too.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand how I could miss the naming case sensitivity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

You **cannot** mix up `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`.

And this should be working now, variable names are case-sensitive:

```
while ($dbresult = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    print_r($dbresult);
    Print "<br><br>";
    Print "Question: ";
    Print $dbresult['Question'];
    Print $dbresult[0];
    Print "<br><br>";
}
```